# async/await trying to stop the windows service

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, windows-services

My program receives events about certain Windows Services starting.
Then if the service matches criteria my program needs to stop the service. It does that using ServiceController. The events coming at random times and since it may take time to  stop the service I don't want that the synchronous stoppage would affect program performance, that is I don't want a delay in handling next incoming service event...

Is the code below that I put together fits the goal?

```
    // event handler calls this function 
    private void ServiceStarted()
    {
        ServiceController svcController = mServiceControllerList.Find(s => 
                                          String.Compare(s.ServiceName, dispName, true) == 0);
        StopServiceAsync(svcController);
    }


    private async Task StopServiceAsync(ServiceController svcController)
    {
        using (Log.VerboseCall())
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                StopService(svcController);
            });
        }
    }

    private void StopService(ServiceController svcController)
    {
        using (Log.VerboseCall())
        {
            // this call by itself is asynchronous - it returns before the service is stopped
            svcController.Stop();
            while (svcController.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
            {
                svcController.Refresh();
                Thread.Sleep(200);
                Log.VerboseFormat("Service {0} is stopping...", svcController.ServiceName);
            }
            //return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Or could launch `net stop name_of_service` DOS command

Comment: That's not what I asked. I know a few other methods to stop the windows service...

Comment: Asynchronous methods should be called from somewhere that have an synchronization context, otherwise it won't be awaited. This way you're making an "fire and forget" method.

Comment: And about performance, async-await won't give you. It only will make your UI responsible and provides scalability because it will free your thread while the operation is running

Comment: My takeaway from your question was that you were looking for a way to stop a service that didn't cause your program any blocking, hence why I made the comment I did

Comment: _"`Is the code below` that I put together `fits the goal?`"_ - I’m voting to close this question because your question with its _["no actual problem to be solved"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)_, kinda sounds like _code improvement_ and/or _review_ and if so may be off-topic for SO.  It _may_ be better suited for another SE site but be sure to read the relevant FAQ; and/or re-wording your question as necessary before cross-posting.  [ask].  Good luck!

Comment: Your code looks fine to me, but as @MickyD pointed out, your question isn't really suited for this site because we don't know what kind of answer you expect. Maybe it would be better on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Service A starts and then my event handler is invoked and calls ServiceStarted. The service info gets retrieved and the service is identified as one that needs to get shutdown. The shutdown process can be quick but it can also last up to 10 seconds. The question is: if  the Service B start within 2 seconds from Service A, will its processing and stopping be blocked by the fact that it takes 10 seconds to stop Service A.

Comment: The code I wrote is an attempt to solve the problem - it is not tested and looks to me not working because there is no other threads invoked... Maybe MickyD did not understand that... If I did not write anything there would be neither to ask about and impossible to explain...